# How to remove all weight elements from table data of multidimensional array with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

After manually appending extra column "CAD data" to multidimensional array with table data, I unfortunately get this lousy [weight] column right before my "CAD data" column.

[Screenshot of my table data output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84WC9.png)

Actually I just want to remove the whole [weight] column before the output again. I tried a few things but nothing successful.

```
Array ( 
    [row_0] => Array ( 
        [col_0] => Order number 
        [col_1] => Size 
        [weight] => 1 
    ) 
    [row_1] => Array ( 
        [col_0] => 502 1001 
        [col_1] => 20 
        [weight] => 2 
    ) 
    [row_2] => Array ( 
        [col_0] => 502 1002 
        [col_1] => 25 
        [weight] => 3 
    ) 
    [row_3] => Array ( 
        [col_0] => 502 1003
        [col_1] => 30 
        [weight] => 4 
    ) 
)
```

And below my code:

```
<?php
$rows = $element['#object']->field_product_data_table['und'][0]['tabledata']['tabledata'];

$header = array_shift($rows);

$attributes = array(
    "id" => "tablefield-0",
    "class" => array("tablefield")
);

// append CAD data column
if (array_key_exists('und', $element['#object']->field_product_step_data)) {
    $header[] = t('CAD data');

    // make index of all entries in table
    $entry_row_id_index = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row_id => &$row) {
        foreach ($row as $entry) {
            $entry_row_id_index[$entry] = $row_id;
        }
    }

    $step_files = $element['#object']->field_product_step_data['und'];

    // add step-file to entry to rows with corresponding order number
    $max_row_length = 0;
    foreach ($step_files as &$file) {
        if (array_key_exists($file['description'], $entry_row_id_index)) {
            $orderNumber = $file['description'];
            $row_id = $entry_row_id_index[$orderNumber];

            $rows[$row_id][] = '<a href="#" class="step-file" data-filename="' . $file['filename'] . '" data-ordernumber="' . $orderNumber . '"></a>';

            $row_length = count($rows[$row_id]);
            if ($row_length > $max_row_length) $max_row_length = $row_length;
        }
    }

    // fill rows so all have same length
    foreach ($rows as $row_id => &$row) {
        for ($i = count($row); $i < $max_row_length; $i++) { 
            $row[] = '';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array_map.
It loops trough every element and creates new array of elements of whatever you want to return.
In your case, you want 'weight' col to be removed, so you unset it.

```
$array1 = [
    [
        'col_0' => '123',
        'col_1' => '321',
        'weight' => 1
    ],
    [
        'col_0' => '123',
        'col_1' => '321',
        'weight' => 1
    ],
    [
        'col_0' => '123',
        'col_1' => '321',
        'weight' => 1
    ],
    [
        'col_0' => '123',
        'col_1' => '321',
        'weight' => 1
    ],
    [
        'col_0' => '123',
        'col_1' => '321',
        'weight' => 1
    ],
];

$array2 = array_map(function($element) {
    unset($element['weight']);
    return $element;
}, $array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate array using [array_map function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$arr = array_map(
    # apply function for each array element
    function ($el) {
        # return modified array elements
        return [
            'col_0'=>$el['col_0'], 
            'col_1'=>$el['col_1']
        ];
    }, 
    $arr
);
```

The code above use array_map with anonymous function that receive each element from source array, manipulate it and return changed element